# what we can tell about this linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $T:\mathbb R^{4}\to \mathbb R^{4}$ be a linear transformation satisfying $T^{3}+3T^{2}=4I$, where $I$ is the identity transformation.  Then the linear transformations $S=T^{4}+3T^{3}-4I$ is:

1. One-one but not onto
2. onto but not one-one
3. Invertible
4. Not invertible

Given $T^{3}+3T^{2}=4I$, let $S=T^{4}+3T^{3}-4I$.  Then:
\begin{align}
S&=T^{4}+3T^{3}-4I\\
&=T(T^{3}+3T^{2})-4I\\
&=4T-4I
\end{align} I think this is not providing any information related to one-one onto so how can I prove it is invertible or not or am I going wrong. Not a homework problem self studying.

Comment: What does the Cayley-Hamilton theorem tell you?

Comment: Since it's a linear transformation $\Bbb R^4 \to \Bbb R^4$, note that the [rank-nullity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem) tells you that the function is injective if and only if it's surjective (it can't be just one; it's both-or-neither here). So, if it's not invertible, none of the others apply.

Answer (score 2):

The rank-nullity theorem implies that options (1) and (2) are impossible. Do you see why?

Note that $T$ is annihilated by the polynomial
$$
p(t)=t^3+3\,t^2-4=(t-1)(t+2)^2
$$
Since the minimal polynomial of $T$ must divide $p(t)$,
it follows that the only potential eigenvalues of $T$ are $1$ and $-2$.

Now, you have correctly proven that
$$
S=4\left(T-I\right)
$$
We have two possible cases:

1. $\lambda=1$ is an eigenvalue of $T$
2. $\lambda=1$ is not an eigenvalue of $T$

If $\lambda=1$ is an eigenvalue of $T$, then $\dim\ker(T-I)=0$ so $S$ is injective. The rank-nullity theorem then implies that $S$ must also be surjective and thus invertible.

If $\lambda=1$ is not an eigenvalue of $T$, then $\dim\ker(T-I)>0$, so $S$ is not injective and thus not invertible.

To see that both cases are possible, note that both of the matrices 
\begin{align*}
T_1&=
\left[\begin{array}{rrrr}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right] &
T_2 &=
\left[\begin{array}{rrrr}
-2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -2 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & -2
\end{array}\right]
\end{align*}
satisfy the given conditions but $1$ is an eigenvalue of $T_1$ and $1$ is not an eigenvalue of $T_2$.

Comment: I think you mean $p(t)$, not $f(t)$.

Comment: The OP has "+3" in the annihilating relation where you have "-3."